# java null pointer exception while running select query in kafka KSQL engine

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Steps :

1. We have created a Kafka topic called `pgsqlcountry` which has all the
   streaming data from postgreSQL DB.
2. we created a stream called `country` for processing the topic into a
   table.
3. stream was created successfully.

-

```
ksql> describe country;

Field      | Type
------------------------------
ROWTIME    | BIGINT
ROWKEY     | VARCHAR(STRING)
ID         | BIGINT
COUNTRY    | VARCHAR(STRING)
CREATED_AT | BIGINT
UPDATED_AT | BIGINT
```

-

4. we run the SQL command "select * from country"
5. we get error as below

-

```
ksql> select * from country;

null | null | null | null | null | null
Exception in thread "ksql_query_1-8f1f36a7-e83c-476d-8561-98fe9ed8866b-StreamThread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please find my stacktrace [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BKtb.jpg)

Comment: i am getting this error "  WARN KsqlJsonDeserializer failed to deserialize data for topic: pgsqlsampletest (io.confluent.ksql.serde.json.KsqlJsonDeserializer:91)"

Comment: You're best logging this as an issue on the KSQL github. And please don't use screenshots for stacktraces - they're text!

Comment: Also include the `CREATE STREAM` declaration (is it delimited or JSON) and the output from the topic itself e.g. with `kafkacat`

Comment: Can you provide a sample row in your topic along with the CREATE STREAM statement that you used. Also what is the format of your data? json?

Answer (score 0):

When I had `java.lang.NullPointerException`, I had incompatible versions of the ksqldb images.

There appears to be the `cp` prefix images, e.g.

- [cp-ksqldb-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server)
- [cp-ksqldb-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli)

Don't mix and match with these images (try to stick with one group or the other):

- [sqldb-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-server)
- [ksqldb-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-cli)

You can run some other commands (e.g. `SHOW PROPERTIES;`) and see if this also gives the same error of `java.lang.NullPointerException`. If it does, it probably is the image.